Recursive Dictionary type definition in Python
I'm trying to define a type that supports the following dict:
test: NestedRecord = {
    "one": "one",
    "two": 2,
    "three": True,
    "four": [1, 2, 3],
    "five": ["one", "two", "three"],
    "another": {
        "one": {"one": ["one"]},
    },
    "six": [{"one": "one"}],
    "seven": [{"one": "one"}, {"two": 2, "three": True}],
    "eight": [{"one": "one"}, {"two": 2, "three": True, "four": {"one": "one"}}],
}

It's a Dict of strings and either strings, nums, bools, lists of them or itself / lists of itself.
I've created this definition:
ValidTypes = Union[str, bool, int, float]
ValidLists = Union[List[str], List[bool], List[int], List[float]]

NestedRecord = Dict[
    str, Union[ValidTypes, ValidLists, "NestedRecord", List["NestedRecord"]]
]

But it errors on the six entry and below:
Dict entry 6 has incompatible type "str": "list[dict[str, str]]"; expected "str": "str | int | float | list[str] | list[bool] | list[int] | list[float] | NestedRecord | list[NestedRecord]" .
It's basically on the typing.List['NestedRecord']. It doesn't support lists of the dictionaries

list is invariant, so list[dict[str, str]] is not a subtype of list[X] with X a supertype of dict[str, str]. Similarly, Dict is invariant. Replacing List with Sequence and Dict with Mapping checks, if you are OK with giving up mutability.

@chepner Actually, there should be no problem since this is an assignment to a variable with explicit type hint. It should be fine for the same reason a: list[NestedRecord] = [{'foo': 'bar'}] is fine.

I'd say this is a Mypy bug. Minimalized example: type NestedRecord = dict[str, str | list[str] | list[NestedRecord]] / test: NestedRecord = {"six": [{"one": "one"}]}.

It would still be a bug involving variance, as switching to covariant types lets the current version accept the assignment.
